# Angular JS : Data binding not working in Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js

I am using ui-date of Angular JS. There are multiple dates which are getting rendered with the loop.Below is my HTML code.

```html
<tr  ng-repeat="(k,v) in :: vm.dateMap">
 <th>
<input ng-attr-id="{{ 'dateCmp-' + k}}" ui-date="vm.dateOptionMap[k]">
</th>
</tr>
```

In my controller, dateOptionMap contains below value

```js
          vm.dateOptionMap = {};
            vm.dateOptionMap['03/06/2014'] = {
                changeYear: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
            };
            vm.dateOptionMap['07/21/2016'] = {
                changeYear: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
            };
            vm.dateOptionMap['09/06/2017'] = {
                changeYear: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
            };
```

On clicking of a button i am changing map value with the below one.

```js
        vm.dateOptionMap['03/06/2014'] = {
                    changeYear: false,
                    changeMonth: false,
                    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
                };
```

How ever this change is not getting reflected on UI. Can you please help me with this ?

Comment: in the end of initializing your data at your controller, use `$scope.$apply()` to update your scope and reflect your changes to the UI, if it solved your problem ask me to submit my solution as an answer

Comment: To achieve two way binding ,you need to use ng-model directive which is missing here

Answer (score 0):

This line `ng-attr-id="{{ 'dateCmp-' + k}}"` only renders a value to the `id` attribute. `ng-attr-id` **DOES NOT BIND** the values.

To Bind your date values to `<input>`, you should set appropriate `js` variable in `ng-model` attribute and then change the value of variable dynamically.